# Intel Daos hadoop-daos jar missing from maven

Tags: intel

Can someone guide me where to find the hadoop-daos jar with classifier - "protobuf3-netty4-shaded"? I tried to download using the [official guide step](https://docs.daos.io/v2.2/user/spark/#maven-download), but it threw below error:

```
$ mvn dependency:get -DgroupId=io.daos -DartifactId=hadoop-daos -Dversion=2.2.0 -Dclassifier=protobuf3-netty4-shaded -Ddest=./
```

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:get (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Couldn't download artifact: Missing:
[ERROR] ----------
[ERROR] 1) io.daos:hadoop-daos:jar:protobuf3-netty4-shaded:2.2.0
[ERROR] 
[ERROR]   Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR]   Then, install it using the command: 
[ERROR]       mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=io.daos -DartifactId=hadoop-daos -Dversion=2.2.0 -Dclassifier=protobuf3-netty4-shaded -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
[ERROR] 
[ERROR]   Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
[ERROR]       mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=io.daos -DartifactId=hadoop-daos -Dversion=2.2.0 -Dclassifier=protobuf3-netty4-shaded -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR]   Path to dependency: 
[ERROR]     1) org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-downloader-plugin:jar:1.0
[ERROR]     2) io.daos:hadoop-daos:jar:protobuf3-netty4-shaded:2.2.0
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] ----------
[ERROR] 1 required artifact is missing.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] for artifact: 
[ERROR]   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-downloader-plugin:jar:1.0
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] from the specified remote repositories:
[ERROR]   central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false)
```